# Disable OutputCaching in MVC3 when running in DEBUG or under Debugger?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to disable output caching in a MVC3 app when in debug.  I am specifying output caching in the controllers (via the attribute) but don't want to have to #if DEBUG all over my code. I expected this to work:

```
// In Web.config.debug
  <system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCache enableOutputCache="false"
                   xdt:Transform="Replace" />
    </caching>
```

But this seems to be ignored.  Any other ideas how to do it system wide without nasty global.asax code or #if DEBUGs everwhere?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `web.config.debug` file is used only when you build a [deployment package](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx). If you run your site locally in Cassini for example it is completely ignored. So you may try disabling cache in your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

and in your `web.config.release` enable the cache. Note though that if you don't use the web deployment package feature those files are completely ignored.

Comment: Found this out just after.  Moved this to the Release version and set it to "true".  Thanks.

Comment: This config seems to doesn't work on IIS Express 8 :(. Why so ?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that would work as well. You may want to also try setting enableFragmentCache to false. Per [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.outputcachesection.enableoutputcache.aspx):

> the EnableFragmentCache property is
>   set to false, no page is cached on the
>   server, regardless of the settings in
>   @ OutputCache directive or caching
>   profile used by the page. For more
>   information, see
>   OutputCacheSettingsSection and
>   OutputCacheProfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS version > 7
You should:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <caching  enabled="true"/> //false in webconfig.debug
  </system.webServer>
```